# Absolute div width inside relative div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem with html/css.

1. I have a container (`position: relative;`) , in my case it is `div.jtk-demo-canvas`
2. Container has floating divs (`position: absolute;`) inside, in my case these are `div.jtk-window`
3. floating divs should have (`position: absolute;`) as it is requirement for js plugin

**Requirement:**
Floating divs should have min-width of 200 and max-width of 400. I dont want to apply width to it as it should vary between 200-400 to fit its content.

But as You can see in my case last div from right is same as 2nd one but its width is lesser.

How can I Fix this ?

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/wm94sf2b/
Since I have large html code, therefore I am posting fiddle link.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

because you gave him `left:800px;` and your body is `width: 960px;` for that your 3rd div only have 160px place

Comment: yes , but it is supposed to scroll since overflow is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Try `display: inline-table` and `position: relative` to div with id **117a13213-102** (Checked in **Chrome** and **Firefox**)

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wm94sf2b/7/)

**CODE**

```
<div style="left: 800px; top: 105px; display: inline-table; position: relative;" id="117a13213-102" class="flowBox jtk-window">
```

Comment: I did not figure it out before but since i am using jsplumb and it requires these divs to be ```position: absolute;```